# How to put Svelte build into Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, svelte

Consider this file structure:

```
dist/
  node_modules/
  public/
    build/
      bundle.css
      bundle.js
    favicon.png
    global.css
    index.html
Dockerfile
package.json
rollup.config.js
```

I wanna create an Node 10 docker image which runs `npm start` executing `node_modules/.bin/sirv public`

Current attempt in Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./dist ./
COPY package.json ./
COPY rollup.config.js ./
EXPOSE 5000
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

After building the image with `docker build -t svelte-docker .`, `docker run -p 5000:5000 svelte-docker` results in this error:

```
> svelte-app@1.0.0 start /app
> sirv public

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './index'
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: i think you should run `RUN npm install` inside your docker file

Comment: No effect @abdoutelb

Comment: Have you tried to `docker run --rm -it svelte-docker sh` to get an interactive debugging shell, so you can see what the filesystem layout inside the image is?

Comment: Try "node dist/public/build" to start the app, instead "npm start". Believing you have build the app before with "npm run build"

Comment: You may want to install deps (e.g. `RUN npm ci`) and then build your assets (e.g. using a bundler: `RUN npm run build`) before you can serve the result files via preferred web server (package.json contains: `"build": "rollup --config rollup.config.js`). I can provide an example for `lighttpd` from one of my recent Svelte apps: https://github.com/sterlett/sterlett/blob/master/docker/dev/lighttpd/Dockerfile-standalone#L59 , but it, probably, couldn't be qualified as an answer, because it doesn't use a native npm solution. Hope it will help to understand a basic workflow tho.

Comment: Also ideas: 1) check your node resolve setup - `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, 2) maybe an import problem? Ensure you are able to resolve AMD-style modules (if you use them) - `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`, example: https://github.com/sterlett/sterlett/blob/0.x/rollup.config.js#L33